# Resize Image inside DIV with Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I need help with this situation... i´m trying to develop a banner rotator (full width), but i didn´t find any solution to strech/resize a slide image (indide a div) 100% width and maintain the aspect ratio. I want to do it with jQuery... does anyone knows a JQuery plugin that solves this situation!!

I Want something sililar of [this](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/) , but applied to a class, because i don´t want this to all images!!!

Please check below an example of  my code. Many thanks in advance!! :)

```
<!-- START BANNER WRAPPER -->
<div id="banner-wrapper">
<div id="banner-full-width">
<div id="main-slider">

  <div class="slide">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="" /> <!-- This is the image i want to fit inside of 100% width div -->
    </div>

    <div class="info">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END BANNER WRAPPER -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about good ol' CSS?

```
.image img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: The think is... i want that this image resize according browser width also!!!
Sorry about my english!! :(

Comment: Make the container resize too, then!

Comment: Don´t work!!! I want this effect... http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/ but applied to a class because i don´t want this to all images!!!!!
By the way, thanks a lot for your help!!!